# Rasterize uses default stylesheet if ImageSize is specified

Tags: bugs, stylesheet, rasterize

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1**

---

If I make a style definition which affects `GraphicsBox`, the style is used by `Rasterize` *unless* I specify an explicit `ImageSize`.

For example, I set a style for `GraphicsLabel`:

[image]

Then I can rasterize a plot and the defined style is used:

```
p = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}];
Rasterize[p]
```

[image]

But if I specify the `ImageSize` the default style is used instead:

```
Rasterize[p, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

I would be interested to know why this happens and how I can work around it, i.e. rasterize at a specific size using the local style definitions.

Comment: Would this work as you'd like? `Rasterize[p, RasterSize -> 200]~Image~{ImageSize -> 200}`

Comment: @Rojo, not quite. That shrinks the labels - what I want is something that looks like `Show[p, ImageSize -> 200]` but in raster form.

Comment: @Rojo, lol - I've just realised the workaround - `Rasterize[Show[p, ImageSize -> 200]]`

Comment: It didn't shrink the labels in here, weird. But glad it triggered a solution over there, hehe

Comment: This looks like a bug. Should this be tagged as bug?

Comment: In the v.8.0.4 `Rasterize[p]` uses the default styles even without `ImageSize`.

Comment: Since Mike's comment has received two upvotes I have taken that as community consensus that this is a bug and have tagged it as such. I will report it to WRI.

Comment: Hello Simon, could you please email me?  I don't have your email address.  Mine is on my profile page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With *Mathematica* version 9.0.1 I can get the result I wanted by specifying the `ImageSize` as a `Graphics` option, e.g. using `Show`, rather than using it as an option to `Rasterize`:

```
Rasterize[Show[p, ImageSize -> 200]]
```

[image]

Note that the labels are still at the size specified in the style sheet.

Interestingly, the custom style **is** used if the graphic is embedded in a non-graphical construct, but in this case the font is demagnified. The following all produce the same output:

```
Rasterize[Style[p, {}], ImageSize -> 200]
Rasterize[Magnify[p, 1], ImageSize -> 200]
Rasterize[Text[p], ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

This is consistent with the documentation for [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rasterize.html) (the first two items under the "Properties and Relations" section) which states:

> Rasterizing a graphic with a custom `ImageSize` option works by changing
>   the graphic's `ImageSize`, not by magnifying the graphic. A graphic
>   embedded in a non-graphical construct will magnify instead.

Comment: I suggested that before you came up with your solution, which I like better. But I am still intrigued why mine works for me. I'm using 9.0.1 on Windows. What about you?

Comment: Ok, I tried it again and the result is something in between the default and custom font size. It rasterizes with the default image size but the custom font size, and then rescales ALL to the custom image size, which is different to what's intended: the font size shouldn't be rescaled. In conclusion, not a solution.

Comment: @Rojo, okay - that's what I see too.

Answer (score 3):

In *Mathematica* 8.0.4 `Rasterize[p]` uses the default styles even without `ImageSize`:

```
$Version

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
     Cell[StyleData["GraphicsLabel"], FontColor -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], FontWeight -> Bold, 
      FontSize -> 16]}, StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]];
```

> ```
> "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 7, 2011)"
> ```

```
p = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}];
Rasterize[p]
```

> [image]

Surprisingly, if we simply wrap `Graphics` by `Style` the Notebook's stylesheet is applied (wrapping by `Pane`, `Text` or `Row` also work):

```
 {Rasterize[Style[p]], Rasterize[Style[p], ImageSize -> 360]}
```

> [image: output]

Unfortunately specifying the stylesheet via `Style` doesn't work (checked with versions 8.0.4 and 11.0.1):

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> Inherited]
Rasterize[Style[p, 
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
     Cell[StyleData["GraphicsLabel"], FontColor -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], FontWeight -> Bold, 
      FontSize -> 16]}, StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]]
```

> [image]

But we can specify it as an option of `Notebook` expression:

```
Rasterize[Notebook[{Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@p, "Output"]}, 
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
     Cell[StyleData["GraphicsLabel"], FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], FontWeight -> Bold, 
      FontSize -> 16]}, StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]]
```

> [image]

Comment: This is a useful trick, but when I specify a reduced `ImageSize` in `Rasterize` I get the labels coming out demagnified.

Comment: @Simon Please clarify what you mean saying that labels are demagnified? I currently work with v.8.0.4 and specifying reduced `ImageSize` gives the labels magnified down as expected, they do not still of the same absolute size in pixels as with the default `ImageSize`. It is what I expect and this behavior is correct from my point of view. If I enlarge `ImageSize` the absolute size of the labels is enlarged as I expect. What is confusing you?

Comment: Alexey, the Properties & Relations section of the `Rasterize` help file shows what I mean. In the first picture the text stays the same size (i.e. the same absolute size in pixels) when the `ImageSize` is changed, this is the behaviour I wanted. In the second picture the text magnifies in proportion to the image size, this is also what happens with your code. Neither behaviour is incorrect, they are just different.

Comment: I see your point, did not know this. In this case `Graphics` is embedded in a non-graphical construct (`Style`) and for this reason is magnified.