# Export Grid object to pdf without border?

Tags: bugs, export, grid-layouts, pdf-format

When I try to export a Grid object with a White background, I get a gray border around 3 of the 4 sides in the resulting pdf:

```
grid4pdf = Grid[{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}}, Background -> White]
Export["thepdfhasborders.pdf", grid4pdf]
```

I get this as the output pdf:

[image]

(the light gray is the Adobe Acrobat Reader background). Any idea why the dark gray border shows up in the pdf, and how I can get rid of it? I typically use the ReverseColor.nb stylesheet, but this behavior persists even in a Default.nb stylesheet notebook.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No problems on 12.3.1 on windows 10.  Screen shot of the PDF generated.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G89zt.png)

Comment: I seem to remember this coming up before….Not sure it was on this site though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Please read up the end: there are *white* borders** with the default stylesheet, and I consider that as a bug in `Export`!

I don't get the gray borders with *Mathematica* 12.3.1 on Windows 10 x64:

```
grid4pdf = 
 Grid[{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}}, 
  Background -> White]
Export["thepdfhasborders.pdf", grid4pdf] // SystemOpen
```

[image: screenshot]

But there is something interesting that I noticed in the FrontEnd when I selected the `Grid` object in the output by the mouse. Notice how the FrontEnd draws the blue border around 3 of the 4 sides of the selection:

[image: screenshot2]

Since it is the FrontEnd who generates the exported PDF file, I suspect it may be related to the issue you observe. The following experiment supports this:

```
grid4pdf = 
  Grid[{{"█", "█", "█"}, {"█", "█", "█"}, {"█", "█", "█"}}, 
   Background -> Red];
Image[image = Rasterize[grid4pdf, Background -> Yellow], 
 Magnification -> 6]
BorderDimensions[image]
```

> [image: output]

Notice the yellow borders around 3 of the 4 sides in the rasterized version of the grid. In the PDF with the default stylesheet we get white borders:

```
Export["thepdfhasborders.pdf", grid4pdf] // SystemOpen
```

[image: screenshot]

Since you mention that you use a custom stylesheet, I suspect that the gray color of the borders may be related to the `Background` setting in that stylesheet. If you have set your stylesheet as the default one by changing the global `DefaultStyleDefinitions` option, you can temporarily return it back using the method from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140003/280) answer:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, DefaultStyleDefinitions] = "Default.nb"
FrontEndTokenExecute["ToggleShowExpression"]
Export["thepdfhasborders.pdf", grid4pdf] // SystemOpen
```

Or you can try the method from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10202/280) answer.

Another method is to export a `Cell` expression with explicit `Background` option:

```
Export["thepdfhasborders.pdf", 
  Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[grid4pdf]], "Output", 
   Background -> White]] // SystemOpen
```

P.S. I consider the addition of the borders as a bug in `Export` since even explicit addition of the options `CellFrameMargins -> 0, CellFrame -> False, ShowCellBracket -> False` doesn't remove the borders. Please report it to the support.

Comment: Thank you so much Alexey! Changing the FrontEnd options via your first code snippet was an effective workaround for me. I've also reported to support as per your suggestion. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Jaffe42 Glad to help. Thank you for reporting!